# Getting rid of a border in a navigation bar with seperate ul's

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to get rid of the "inbetween" borders of the nav bar.
I have numerous ul's and li's and it seems to be interfering with my nav bar even though I assigned classes to it.
Here's a pic what it should look like:
[image]

```css
    body{
    background-image: url("../Images/bg.jpg");
    color: white;
}
h1{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 4em;
    
}
h2{
    height: 56px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.white{
    color: white
}
.blue{
    color: #00bfff
}

li{
    display: block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 4px;
}
ul{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    
}
.small{
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
}
.red{
    background-color: #FF4500;
}
.orange{
    background-color: #FF8C00;
}
.yellow{
    background-color: #FFBF00;
}
.brown{
    background-color: #9C6E03;
}
.black{
    background-color: #0d1a00
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 184px;
}
.zoom{
    width: 370px;
    height: 600px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url("../Images/bg.jpg");
    margin-top: -50px;
}
.menuUl{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden
}
.menuLi{
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: firebrick;
    border-radius: 5px:
}
```

note: I am aware that the href links aren't in yet.

JS fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rsgq3v5e/

Comment: can't replicate your issue

Comment: Are you sure it is the UL? Is there a div around it? `.menuUL { border: 0px }` will get rid of it.

Comment: What do you mean the "inbetween borders"?

Comment: I'll input my entire CSS,

Comment: With in between borders I mean the lines between the words. it makes a border around every word as well as the rest of the line.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7n33ytmc/ Do you want this? .menuLi - border:none? And to remove left and right border from menu Ul: https://jsfiddle.net/7n33ytmc/1/ ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  background-color:#222;
}

.menuUl {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top:2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}
.menuLi {
  float: left;
  
}
li a {
  border-radius:5px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuUl">
  <li class="menuLi"><a class="active" href="EindOpdracht.html">COURSES</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuLi"><a href="">INFO DAY</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuLi"><a href="">LOCATIONS</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body {
  background-color:#222;
}

.menuUl {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: solid 1px #EEE;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #EEE;
}
.menuLi {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;  
  border-radius: 10px;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuUl">
  <li class="menuLi"><a class="active" href="EindOpdracht.html">COURSES</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuLi"><a href="">INFO DAY</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuLi"><a href="">LOCATIONS</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menuUl {
list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #424242;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;

}
.menuLi {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #e65e0f;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
```